# How can I do a hash set of type object based on id’s or names?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I do a hash set of type object based on id’s or names?  I’ve tried this…

```
    var studentList= from sl in db.Assignments where sl.teacherId==id && sl.DayOfWeek==dayofweek select sl;
                            var newStudentList = new HashSet<Assignment>(studentList);
```

…but it doesn’t filter enough.   For example I have some records that contain multiple entries.

```
 Name       Subject          Date        ID 

 John       Math             6-12        7
 John       Math             6-18        7 
 Mary       English          6-12        8 
 Mary       English          6-18        8 
 Mary       Math             6-12        8 
 John       Math             6-27        7 
 John       English          6-12        7 
 John       English          6-18        7 
 John       Art              6-12        7 
 John       Art              6-18        7
```

I want to filter for no repetition and returns a list of entities that looks like this ignoring the date.

```
 John            Math                    7
 Mary            English                 8 
 Mary            Math                    8 
 John            English                 7 
 John            Art                     7
```

Can I use a HashSet to do this?  If HashSet does not work, can you please suggest another way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can filter this out on the DB level, then just use `Distinct`.

If it's not possible, one simple solution is to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on your object. `HashSet` will pick them up and use them for equality comparisons.

Another solution would be to use the following `DistinctBy` function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, TProp> selector, IEqualityComparer<TProp> equalityComparer = null)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<TProp>(equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TProp>.Default);
    return sequence.Where(item => seen.Add(selector(item)));
}
```

and then use:

```
students.DistinctBy(s => new { s.Name, s.Subject, ... });
```

These two last solutions will only work on linq to objects.